# What is this IC with marking M7CK 825?

Tags: voltage, identification, components, repair, sonar

[image][image][image][image][image: photo of PCB showing unknown component]

What device has this marking M7CK 825 with size 3mm x 3mm, so I can purchase a replacement? This is a Garmin echomap 50s sonar circuit board. The outboard gave overcurrent and this broke down, as did one capacitor. Here are two boards Thanks.

Comment: Can You provide wider image of the board, also the other side?

Comment: There seem to be inductors and freewheeling diodes on the other side of the board right on top of those chips. So I'm guessing they're switching voltage regulators. Can't find any with those markings tough.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [MPS MPQ4460DQ](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MPQ4460/document_id/316/) step-down converter.

[image]

I can't find a picture of this IC, but I know that MPS uses this markings style. Here is a picture of a MPS IC with the marking `N4` from a [previous identification question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/657448/identifying-10-pin-smd-chip-with-code-n4ge-525/676065#676065):

[image]

(Source: [aliexpress.com](https://id.aliexpress.com/i/1005001827294227.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2idn))