# Identifying 10-pin SMD chip with code N4GE 525

Tags: power-supply, identification, components, surface-mount

[image]

Please help identify this 10-pin SMD chip with top marking N4GE 525 which is from a KUKA robotic arm programming console (SmartPad-1).

Two pieces are used in the power supply regulation section. There is no other code on the back side. The body size is 3 mm x 3 mm.

Comment: Please edit the question to include high resolution pictures of the board that include the chip and the area around it - say a 2x2" picture.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [MPS MPQ4459DQT](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/277/MPQ4459-2946660.pdf) 36V Step-Down Converter.

[image]

This is the highest quality image I could find. The marking style matches.

[image]
(Source: [aliexpress.com](https://id.aliexpress.com/i/1005001827294227.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2idn))